# CSS animation begins on hover, then stops

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

thanks in advance for any help.

I've been working with a few effects to find something I like, and stumbled across this site:
https://www.marieforleo.com/

The 3rd section down (black bg) has the word "anything" underlined, and when you roll over it, it sets off a sequence where that word changes to a variety of other words.

I've tried to find a related tutorial but no luck. Wondering if anyone might be able to point the way toward achieving this effect, whether through css3 alone or with jquery. Ideally the animation would stop after it reaches the end of its "word options".

Thanks all!

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Saurav, thanks! This type of code isn't my primary forte, so I've mostly been adapting other things I've found. I tried working with these (https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-animated-headlines/) and liked it, but the effect was too intrusive for what we need. I also tried https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/17/rotating-words-with-css-animations/, but couldn't find a way to stop the looping animation, which made it overly distracting. 

For these purposes, I started realizing something on hover would work better, which led me to the effect I posted. Beyond that, I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with pure CSS: "animate" the content of pseudo element

```css
.words::before {
  content: "hello";
}

.words:hover::before {
  animation: rotateWords 5s;
}

@keyframes rotateWords {
  20% { content: 'world' }
  40% { content: 'foo' }
  60% { content: 'bar' }
  80% { content: 'lorem' }
  100% { content: 'ipsum' }
}
```

```html
<span class="words"></span>
```

Comment: Hi Aziz, thanks for the remarkably quick reply! This is a great start. Any way to randomize the results, rather than them showing in the same order each time?

Comment: One other note - I noticed on marieforleo.com that the top left logo at the very top of the page has a similar effect. Thanks again so much for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to randomly select a word and inject it on hover. If that's not what you're looking for, you could use a for loop in a sass mixin. Something like this should work.

```
@mixin randomword

$words: word1, word2, word3; //array with desired words

@for $i from 1 through length($words) { //this loops through the array
  .words:hover {
    content: nth($words,random(length($words)); //random number generator
  }
}
```

This should select a word from the $words list, at a random position between 1 and the length of the words list. This will word assuming your initial word is being pulled from a content block.